# What is Japanese version of the pun word, "slife"? ... and term for adult friend?

Tags: japanese-language, reincarnated-as-a-slime

At time code 21:40 of [Episode 1](https://www.crunchyroll.com/that-time-i-got-reincarnated-as-a-slime/episode-1-the-storm-dragon-veldora-777519) of *That Time I Got Reincarnated as a Slime*, the protagonist Satoru refers to his new life as a slime as a "slife" (sub).  I'm guessing there was similar word play in Japanese.  Could someone explain what it was?
[image]

Also, just prior to that he had made friends with a dragon, but as a 37-year-old (former) human, seemed embarrassed to use the term "friends".  Does Japanese tend to use a different term than "friend" for adults?  I get the impression Satoru thinks the term would normally be used by kids and teenagers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a play on 人生 (jinsei, lit. human life) with スライム生 (suraimusei, lit. slime life).

'Slife' is an accurate portmanteau here. Since it's Slime + Life.

Friends are friends regardless of age. There are more formal words like 友人 (yujin), but how it's used is circumstantial and highly contextual in nature.

Comment: You can ask about the nuances over at Japanese.SE, if you are curious.

Comment: Thank you, @кяαzєя . I posted a follow-up at https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/62197/why-would-a-japanese-adult-be-embarrassed-to-use-the-word-friends .